# openjdk-6-jre-headless dependency in debian jessie

Tags: debian

i was trying to install flowvisor on debian jessie. but i get the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
flowvisor : Depends: openjdk-6-jre-headless which is a virtual package.
```

But i have these package installed already:

```
default-jre-headless
openjdk-7-jre-headless
libjpeg8
```

so what should i install next?
Thanks!

Comment: From where are you installing the package, which what command?

Comment: these are aptitude output!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated by [yaegashi](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/116972/yaegashi), the package depends on `openjdk-6-jre-headless` which isn't available in Debian Jessie. It is available in Debian unstable, so you could install it from there if you really want to, but the suggestion to request a new package of `flowvisor` is better (OpenJDK 6 is old and I don't know how good its security support is).

In the meantime, you can use `equivs` to build a fake package which pulls in `openjdk-7-jre-headless` instead:

```
# as root
apt-get install equivs

# as yourself
equivs-control openjdk-6-jre-headless.control
```

Edit the resulting `openjdk-6-jre-headless.control` file so it contains the following:

```
### Commented entries have reasonable defaults.
### Uncomment to edit them.
Source: openjdk-6
Section: java
Priority: optional
# Homepage: <enter URL here; no default>
Standards-Version: 3.9.6

Package: openjdk-6-jre-headless
Version: 7u79-2.5.5-1
Maintainer: Your Name <youremail@example.org>
Depends: openjdk-7-jre-headless
Architecture: all
# Copyright: <copyright file; defaults to GPL2>
# Changelog: <changelog file; defaults to a generic changelog>
# Readme: <README.Debian file; defaults to a generic one>
# Extra-Files: <comma-separated list of additional files for the doc directory>
# Files: <pair of space-separated paths; First is file to include, second is destination>
#  <more pairs, if there's more than one file to include. Notice the starting space>
Description: OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT (headless)
 Minimal Java runtime - needed for executing non GUI Java programs,
 using Hotspot JIT.
 .
 The packages are built using the IcedTea build support and patches
 from the IcedTea project.
 .
 This dummy package depends on OpenJDK 7.
```

(replacing the values in the `Maintainer:` line). Then generate the dummy package:

```
 equivs-build openjdk-6-jre-headless.control
```

and install it:

```
 # as root
 dpkg -i openjdk-6-jre-headless_7u79-2.5.5-1_all.deb
```

You should then be able to install `flowvisor`. If it doesn't use the `openjdk-6` paths explicitly it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The package explicitly depends on `openjdk-6-jre-headless` from [openjdk-6](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/openjdk-6) which is removed from the Debian jessie release.  Supposedly it has to depend on `default-jre-headless` instead to fix the problem.

Debian doesn't have the official package for flowvisor.  It's likely for you to retrieve from the 3rd party repository mentioned [here](https://github.com/opennetworkinglab/flowvisor/wiki/Installation-from-Binary).  You could modify and rebuild the source package for jessie by yourself, or contact the package maintainer to ask for that.